# When using the three. js WebGLRenderTarget, there is a problem when the plane is attached to the sphere？

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Thank you very much for coming to see this problem. I don't know much about THREE, but I need to use it

picture：
[image]

[image]

```
 const RTScene = this.vr.scene;
      this.RTScene = RTScene;
      var renderer = this.vr.renderer;
      var camera = this.vr.camera;
      var materials = []; //创建一个贴图数组
      const video1 = document.getElementById("videos1");
      const texture1 = new THREE.VideoTexture(video1);
      texture1.maxFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
      texture1.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400, 200, 3, 3);
      // const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 32, 32, 0, 6.28, 3.14, 3.14);
      this.handleGetTxture();
      materials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture1,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      });

var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
      this.planegeometry = geometry;
      this.bufferGeometry = bufferGeometry;
      // var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(bufferGeometry, materials); //网格模型对象Mesh
      mesh.position.z = 200;
      RTScene.add(mesh); //网格模型添加到场景中
      const RenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(1000, 1000, {
        minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
        wrapS:THREE.RepeatWrapping
      });
      this.RenderTarget = RenderTarget;
      this.vr.RenderTarget = RenderTarget;
      this.vr.RTScene = RTScene;
```

```
var scene = this.vr.scene;
      var renderer = this.vr.renderer;
      var camera = this.vr.camera;
      var RenderTarget = this.RenderTarget;
      var obj = this.vr.VRObject.getObjectByName("__mxrealityDefault");

      if (obj) {
        obj.material.map = RenderTarget.texture;
        // obj.material.map = RenderTarget.texture;
      }
```

It is strange that the texture of the sphere post is blurred and serrated and not as good as I thought. Do I need to make any Settings or method calls

Comment: Using `THREE.NearestFilter` will always give you this kind of pixellated or "serrated" look. What are you trying to accomplish with that filter?

Comment: Can I paste renderTarget.texture on the sphere like a panorama? I find I'm only on part of the sphere